# error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type...from a temporary of type

Tags: c++, reference, initialization, constants, pass-by-reference

I thought I could create and populate a C++ map like this:

```
 39 int main(){
 40 
 41   cout << "Approximate travelling salesman path finder." << endl;
 42   cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl << endl;
 43 
 44   map<City, OtherCities> database; 
 45   ReadInData(&database);
 46   ... 
 47 }
```

As a side note, the `ReadInData` function just takes a `map<City, OtherCities>` reference as an argument, where `City` is just a typedef of string (the name of a city), and `OtherCities` is a priority queue containing (string, int) pairs that represent other cities and their distances from the first one.

Anyway, attempting to compile this leads to the following error:

```
pr3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
pr3.cpp:45: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::priority_queue<OtherCity, std::vector<OtherCity, std::allocator<OtherCity> >, std::greater<OtherCity> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::priority_queue<OtherCity, std::vector<OtherCity, std::allocator<OtherCity> >, std::greater<OtherCity> > > > >&’ from a temporary of type ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::priority_queue<OtherCity, std::vector<OtherCity, std::allocator<OtherCity> >, std::greater<OtherCity> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::priority_queue<OtherCity, std::vector<OtherCity, std::allocator<OtherCity> >, std::greater<OtherCity> > > > >*’
```

What am I doing wrong here, and (besides using a taboo global variable), is there another nice way to keep the the `database` in the main function and populate/use it elsewhere? I didn't want to just pass a copy of it by value...

Comment: `database` is **not** an _uninitialized variable_. Assuming `map` refers to `std::map`, which has a default constructor, `database` is _default constructed_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the function takes a reference, you should pass `database`, not `&database` The latter is the *address* of `database`, so it's a pointer, not a reference.

Comment: OHH...Oops. You're getting the best answer check mark in ~8 minutes when I can give it...ha ha.

Answer (score 1):

Like what you said, `ReadInData()` is like this:

```
ReadInData(map<City, OtherCities>& param)
//                               ^
//                            NOTICE THIS
```

It takes `param` by *reference*. Thus, you should do:

```
map<City, OtherCities> database; 
ReadInData(database);
//         ^
//      BYE-BYE &
```

and not `ReadInData(&database);` because with that, you are actually *passing the address* of `database` to `ReadInData()`, which is not what `ReadInData()` needs.